# Saying "I will be doing my home work." in German

Tags: sentence-structure, tense

I hope it is clear, I would like to say "I will be doing my home work in 2 hours". I mean I will be in action in 2 hours. It can be said like that?
Ich werde in zwei Stunden meine Hausaufgaben machen. 
Thanks!

Comment: And not a minute more ! I have your word ! Seriously, if that is a question "can it be said" then, yes, it can.

Comment: What's about using [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/I%20will%20be%20doing%20my%20home%20work%20in%202%20hours%0A) before asking here? Please note, your question is off-topic on SE German language (see [on-topic](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @a_donda it was question, sorry forgot question mark.

Answer (score 4):

- "Ich werde in zwei Stunden meine Hausaufgaben machen." is correct but may sound somewhat formal due to the use of future tense.
- Everyday spoken German would probably use present tense: "Ich mache meine Hausaufgaben in zwei Stunden."

Both sentences are a bit ambiguous whether the homeworks starts in 2 hours or whether the duration is two hours. "In zwei Stunden fange ich mit meinen Hausaufgaben an." would be unambiguous. As would be: "Für meine Hausaufgaben brauche ich zwei Stunden."